How to make cmd window pop up and/or alert user in python?
I have made a python script to monitor a critical equipment. The engineer using it may/will minimize the cmd window and work on something else while the program runs in the background. Is there any way that I can make the window pop up on the screen?
I asked around and some of the suggestions were: create a pop-up window using tkinter but I feel it is too OP for the task at hand. A simple line which will make the window pop and display if hidden/minimized.

I can do os.system("start alert.exe") which will create another cmd window and alert the user

For Windows, call the MessageBox API. A system model message box will pop up in front of other windows.
It can be called with the 3rd-party pywin32 module:
from win32ui import MessageBox
from win32con import MB_OK, MB_SYSTEMMODAL, MB_ICONEXCLAMATION

MessageBox('Text', 'Caption', MB_OK | MB_SYSTEMMODAL | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION)

Or with the built-in ctypes module:
import ctypes as ct
import ctypes.wintypes as w

MB_ICONEXCLAMATION = 0x00000030
MB_SYSTEMMODAL = 0x00001000
MB_OK = 0

# Handler to raise exception if API is called incorrectly.
def zeroerrorcheck(result, func, args):
    if not result:
        raise ct.WinError(ct.get_last_error())
    return result

# Fully declared for type-checking and error handling.
user32 = ct.WinDLL('user32', use_last_error=True)
MessageBox = user32.MessageBoxW
MessageBox.argtypes = w.HWND, w.LPCWSTR, w.LPCWSTR, w.UINT
MessageBox.restype = ct.c_int
MessageBox.errcheck = zeroerrorcheck

# Example
MessageBox(None, 'Text', 'Caption', MB_OK | MB_SYSTEMMODAL | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION)



Bringing a terminal window to the foreground is specific to the type of terminal window and the operating system it is running on. Whether the terminal window is in the foreground and has focus or not is an attribute of the window in the windowing system, while your script typically runs as a console application (text only).
The solution you suggested in the comments, executing os.system("start alert.exe") could work, if there's an alert.exe in the working directory of the script, or to be found somewhere on the path. But it won't generally work, not even on any Windows machine with the script running in the same terminal (Windows Terminal, Windows Console Host, possibly others).
The suggestion given to you, to create a window with tkinter is more broadly applicable. It would work on any operating system that runs Python, since it makes use of a standard library and whatever the environment is, that library will have implemented some way of getting the user's attention, if there's a windowing system at all.
However, if you're just looking for a solution that works on a specific OS, in the terminal window you're currently using (apparently on Windows), the following works:
import ctypes
import sys

# obtain a handle for the console window
kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32')
user32 = ctypes.WinDLL('user32')
hWnd = kernel32.GetConsoleWindow()

if hWnd:
    # restore the window if it is minimized
    user32.ShowWindow(hWnd, 9)  # 9 is 'SW_RESTORE'
    # bring it to the foreground
    user32.SetForegroundWindow(hWnd)
else:
    print("No console window found.")

I would not recommend running other programs (like the start.exe, or any other program you need to launch through os.system or subprocess.run) if your aim is to bring the window you're running in to the foreground. It just complicates things with more dependencies and the need to find a handle to your own window. Solutions like tkinter at least give you a window you control, but they don't do what you're asking, which is to bring the main console window to the front.
The code example given here will generally work on Windows, in either Windows Terminal (the default in Windows 11) or the Windows Console Host (the default prior to Windows Terminal, what people would see 'Command Prompt' in), without the need for additional software, using only standard libraries available in windows versions of CPython (which is the commonly used version).

On Windows, you could try running Powershell with a command that shows an alert inside a MessageBox
Something like
import subprocess

subprocess.run(["powershell", "-Command", "Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework;[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('Hello World')"], capture_output=True)

You might have to make sure you can run Powershell scripts first
